# WooCommerce : [woocommerce_checkout] shortcode displays checkout form but not payment methods

Tags: woocommerce

Using the `[woocommerce_checkout]` shortcode (`do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]')` in my Ajax-loaded PHP code) I can display the checkout form wherever I want. But payment methods are missing. How can I have these too?

Comment: Consider also posting in [WordPress Development StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Nope, my last WooCommerce-related questions were rejected there :/

Comment: Wow... ?   I'm a bit frustrated with my 1-question experience there, if that makes you feel any better.

Comment: drake035, did you ever fixed this and got the checkout to fully work with shortcode ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not calling the ajax from cart or checkout page you need to set WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT = true before calling shortcode;

```
    define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
    echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]');
```

Comment: Thx @Swarnendu, payment methods now show up but checkout form submit gives "Error: There was a problem connecting to the payment gateway", whereas it works the first time with default WP theme (but with same plugins active). Any idea?

Comment: Additional clue: on default WP theme clicking "place order" button triggers Ajax functionality (with Ajax loader appearing) before redirecting to Order Received page. But with this custom code, no Ajax functionality seems to occur, the same Checkout page reloads with the error message I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug.
I've reviewed the code and found out that `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>` on form-checkout.php is not able to run the hook `add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );` if using shortcode `[woocommerce_checkout]`.

Comment: Ok, any way around this bug?